# Modify object property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var foo = [{ bar: 1, baz: [1,2,3] }, { bar: 2, baz: [4,5,6] }];

var filtered = $.grep(foo, function(v){
    return v.bar === 1;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98EsQ/

Is there any way to modify a certain objects property (like the one I'm filtering out above) without creating new arrays and/or objects?

Desired result: `[{ bar: 1, baz: [11,22,33] }, { bar: 2, baz: [4,5,6] }]`

Comment: @squint I was looking for a method which allowed me to "point" at a certain object and let me alter it (either in ES or jQuery). But I guess I have to do it manually with a foreach :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Sure, just change it:

With jQuery's `$.each`:

```
$.each(foo, function() {
    if (this.bar === 1) {
        this.baz[0] = 11;
        this.baz[1] = 22;
        this.baz[2] = 33;
        // Or: `this.baz = [11, 22, 33];`
    }
});
```

With ES5's `forEach`:

```
foo.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj.bar === 1) {
        obj.baz[0] = 11;
        obj.baz[1] = 22;
        obj.baz[2] = 33;
        // Or: `obj.baz = [11, 22, 33];`
    }
});
```

...or you have [other looping options in this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-a-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 86):

`.map` with *spread* (`...`) operator

`var result = foo.map(el => el.bar == 1 ? {...el, baz: [11,22,33]} : el);`

Comment: I cant update "baz" based on prev value,only change prop value completely.

Answer (score 36):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and change its property.

```js
let foo = [{ bar: 1, baz: [1,2,3] }, { bar: 2, baz: [4,5,6] }];

let obj = foo.find(f=>f.bar==1);
if(obj)
  obj.baz=[2,3,4];
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: this is useful only if you know you'll always have a single match

Comment: @AdiG true. If you are looking at multiple it would be better to use `map` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45341784/4826457)

Answer (score 11):

We can also achieve this by using Array's map function:

```
 foo.map((obj) => {
   if(obj.bar == 1){
     obj.baz[0] = 11;
     obj.baz[1] = 22;
     obj.baz[2] = 33;
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 10):

Without jQuery and backwards compatibility

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    if (foo[i].bar === 1) {
        foo[i].baz = [11,12,13];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    const objArr = [
        {prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value11'},
        {prop1: 'value2', prop2: 'value22'},
        {prop1: 'value3', prop2: 'option33'},
        {prop1: 'value4', prop2: 'option44'}
    ]

    const newObjArr = objArr.map(obj => {
            if (['value1', 'value2'].includes(obj.prop1)) {
                return {...obj, prop1: 'newValue'}
            }
            return obj
        }
    )
    
    // const responseGotten = [
    //     { prop1: 'newValue', prop2: 'value11' },
    //     { prop1: 'newValue', prop2: 'value22' },
    //     { prop1: 'value3', prop2: 'option33' },
    //     { prop1: 'value4', prop2: 'option44' }
    // ]
```

Answer (score 4):

But before opting any of the mentioned techniques please keep in mind the performance challenges associated with each of the approach.

```
Object iterate For-In, average: ~240 microseconds.

Object iterate Keys For Each, average: ~294 microseconds.

Object iterate Entries For-Of, average: ~535 microseconds.
```

Reference - [3 JavaScript Performance Mistakes You Should Stop Doing](https://hackernoon.com/3-javascript-performance-mistakes-you-should-stop-doing-ebf84b9de951)

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(foo,function(index,value)
{
    if(this.bar==1)
    {
this.baz[0] = 11;
        this.baz[1] = 22;
        this.baz[2] = 33;
    }

});
```

but for loop is faster than $.each so u can try to use

```
for(var i=0; i <foo.length; i++)
{

if(foo[i].bar==1)
{
//change the code
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can play around:

```js
const tasks = [ { id: 1, done: false }, { id: 2, done: false } ]
const completed_task = { id: 1, done: true }

const markCompleted = (tasks, task) => {
  const index = tasks.findIndex(t => t.id === task.id);
  tasks.splice(index, 1);
  tasks.push(task);
  return tasks;
}

console.log(tasks)
console.log(markCompleted(tasks, completed_task))
```

**EDIT**

to avoid index change:

```
const markCompleted = (tasks, task) => {
      const index = tasks.findIndex(t => t.id === task.id);
      tasks[index] = task;
      return tasks;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of filter function of javascript.

```js
obj = [
    {inActive:false, id:1},
    {inActive:false, id:2},
    {inActive:false, id: 3}
];
let nObj = obj.filter(ele => {
    ele.inActive = true;
    return ele;
});

console.log(nObj);
```

Comment: Wouldn't map be more semantically correct?  You are not really filtering anything, since your intent the whole time is to return every element.  Also, you're not really altering the object, either, just creating a copy that is changed.  I think OP specifically said no new objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the array by using simple for loop

```js
var foo = [{ bar: 1, baz: [1,2,3] }, { bar: 2, baz: [4,5,6] }];
for(i = 0;i < foo.length;i++){
  //Here your condition for which item you went to edit
    if(foo[i].bar == 1){
    //Here you logic for update property
        foo[i].baz= [1,11,22]
    }
}
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myArray = [
{ id: 1, body: "wash dishes", state: "done" },
{ id: 2, body: "wash car", state: "onGoing" },
{ id: 3, body: "wash hands", state: "done" },
]

myArray.findIndex(function(obj){  //it will search between every object in array
    if (obj.body=="wash car"){ //find the object you looking for and pass to obj
        obj.state = "done"   // you can select and update any part you want here
    }

console.log(myArray) // see the updatet array
```