# Applying a method to JavaScript object on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically loaded object for which the print of `JSON.stringify()` in the console looks like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1046
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814734.1764,
            "y": 5130578.545900002
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1051
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814335.3286,
            "y": 5130497.9344
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1052
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814639.1784,
            "y": 5130583.1822
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1053
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814496.7964,
            "y": 5130560.822300002
        }
    }
];
```

How can I apply `.toFixed(2)` function to each of `X` and `Y` in `geometry` nodes on the fly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify object property in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691833/modify-object-property-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`

```
data = data.map( function(s){
  s.geometry.x = s.geometry.x.toFixed(2);
  s.geometry.y = s.geometry.y.toFixed(2);
  return s;
})
```

**Edit**

Or with `forEach`

```
data.forEach( function(s){
  s.geometry.x = s.geometry.x.toFixed(2);
  s.geometry.y = s.geometry.y.toFixed(2);
})
```

Comment: I do not think we need `.map` here. `s` is an object, so it will mutate original object in array anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
const formattedData = data.map(d => {
  d.geometry.x = parseFloat(d.geometry.x).toFixed(2);
  d.geometry.y = parseFloat(d.geometry.y).toFixed(2);

  return d;
})
```

Feel free to change the property name (`x` -> `xFormatted`) if you don't wish to override the original data.

Comment: Unfortunately, Gurvinder beat you by 30 secs

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
//Your Data
var data = [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1046
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814734.1764,
            "y": 5130578.545900002
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1051
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814335.3286,
            "y": 5130497.9344
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1052
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814639.1784,
            "y": 5130583.1822
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1053
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": -9814496.7964,
            "y": 5130560.822300002
        }
    }
];


//Updating data 
data.forEach(function(item,index){
  item["geometry"]["x"]=item["geometry"]["x"].toFixed(2);
  item["geometry"]["y"]=item["geometry"]["y"].toFixed(2);
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate using the forEach function. Also make sure to parse the value using `parseFloat` before calling the `toFixed` function.

```
data.forEach(entry => {
    entry.geometry.x = parseFloat(entry.geometry.x).toFixed(2);
    entry.geometry.y = parseFloat(entry.geometry.y).toFixed(2);
});
```