# Concatenate a string to each object of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array looking like this:

```
myArray = [[EnterNode {name: "name1", _value_: 12.32 }],
           [EnterNode {name: "name2", _value_: 42.39 }],
           [EnterNode {name: "name3", _value_: 77.32 }],
           [EnterNode {name: "name4", _value_: 52.31 }],
           ...
]
```

I don't know what `EnterNode` means but this is how it looks like when I print it in the console.

I want to each `_value_` to concatenate a string, for example `" kg"` so after this procedure the array to look like this:

```
myArray = [[EnterNode {name: "name1", _value_: "12.32 kg" }],
           [EnterNode {name: "name2", _value_: "42.39 kg" }],
           [EnterNode {name: "name3", _value_: "77.32 kg" }],
           [EnterNode {name: "name4", _value_: "52.31 kg" }],
           ...
]
```

I tries to do it like this:

`myArray.forEach(_value_ => _value_ + " kg")` but I get `undefined` as result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `.map` instead of `.forEach`. Foreach doesn't return anything, whereas map returns a copy of the modified array

Comment: did it like that and my array contains now these: `"[object Object] kg"`

Comment: Not exact duplicate but should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691833/modify-object-property-in-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> myArray.forEach(*value* => *value* + " kg") but I get undefined as
>   result.

Because you are not saving the value back to `_value_` property of each item of the array

Make it

```
myArray.forEach( obj => ( obj._value_ += " kg" ) );
```

observe that iteration happens on the item of the array rather than `_value_`

**Demo**

```js
var myArray = [
   {name: "name1", _value_: 12.32 },
   {name: "name2", _value_: 42.39 },
   {name: "name3", _value_: 77.32 },
   {name: "name4", _value_: 52.31 }
];

myArray.forEach( obj => ( obj._value_ += " kg" ) ); 
 
console.log( myArray );
```