# Change boolean in the filtered array

Tags: javascript

I have array and i need to write a function that accepts the name of the user and and boolean should be changed to true.

```js
var array = [{
  user: "Sasha",
  message: "Hello guys",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}, {
  user: "Sasha",
  message: "How are you doing",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}, {
  user: "Dima",
  message: "I am fine, thanks!",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}, {
  user: "Katya",
  message: "I am doing well! What about you?",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}]

function readMessage(user) {
  let test = array
  let filtered = test.filter(item => item.user === user);
  let y = filtered.map(item => item.user && !item.read);
  console.log(y);
}

readMessage();
```

I think i should filter array, and then change bool to the opposite, but after that map function returns only bools. How to change boolean and push changes to the original array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify object property in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691833/modify-object-property-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: `.map` and `.filter` create copies of the original array, you need to use `for` or `.forEach` and operate on `user` directly if you want to modify the original array

Answer (score 1):

First you need to filter the array with your desired value, then you get a filtered array, now you map over that array to update the boolean value.

```js
// put your messages array in a variable
var array = [{
  user: "Sasha",
  message: "Hello guys",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}, {
  user: "Sasha",
  message: "How are you doing",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}, {
  user: "Dima",
  message: "I am fine, thanks!",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}, {
  user: "Katya",
  message: "I am doing well! What about you?",
  time: "20:28:2",
  read: false
}]

function readMessage(user) {
  let test = array
  let filtered = test.filter(item => item.user === user);
  // console.log(filtered); // check the filtered array;
  filtered.map(item => item.read = true);
  console.log(filtered);
}
// call the function now;
readMessage('Sasha');
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code worked **but just returns your filtered/mapped values**:

```
array.filter(item => item.user === 'Sasha').map(item => item.read = true)
```

**In your function return the array instead**

```
array.filter(item => item.user === user).map(item => item.read = true)
return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set read to true inside the map function like this:

```
function readMessage(user){
   let test = array
   let filtered = test.filter(item => item.user === user);
   let y = filtered.map(item => item.read = true);
}
```

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

This version does not modify your messages in place but only returns the filtered, updated list:

```js
const items = [
  {user: "Sasha", message: "Hello guys", time: "20:28:2", read: false},
  {user: "Sasha", message: "How are you doing", time: "20:28:2", read: false},
  {user: "Dima", message: "I am fine, thanks!", time: "20:28:2", read: false},
  {user: "Katya", message: "I am doing well! What about you?", time: "20:28:2", read: false}
] 

const readMessages = (items, user) => items
  .filter(item => item.user === user)
  .map(({read, ...rest}) => ({...rest, read: !read}))

const updatedItems = readMessages(items, 'Sasha')

console.log(updatedItems)
```

This version returns a new entire list of messages, with the matching ones changed:

```js
const items = [
  {user: "Sasha", message: "Hello guys", time: "20:28:2", read: false},
  {user: "Sasha", message: "How are you doing", time: "20:28:2", read: false},
  {user: "Dima", message: "I am fine, thanks!", time: "20:28:2", read: false},
  {user: "Katya", message: "I am doing well! What about you?", time: "20:28:2", read: false}
] 

const updatedMessages = (items, userToCheck) => items
  .map(({user, read, ...rest}) => user == userToCheck
      ? {...rest, user, read: !read}
      : {...rest, user, read}
  )

const updatedItems = updatedMessages(items, 'Sasha')

console.log(updatedItems)
```

And this version updates the list of items in place.  (I would recommend against this unless it's absolutely necessary.  Immutable data has great benefits!)

```
const updateMessages = (items, userToCheck) => {
  items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.user == userToCheck) {
      item.read = !item.read
    }
  })
  return items
}
```