# how to add a number to a integer field using nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection like this.

```
 {
"_id": "6137392141bbb7723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":9000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":9000000002`
}
```

Aim is to update the phonenumber field with 91. i want to insert 91 infront each and every phonenumber of users.

```
{
"_id": "6137392141bbb7723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000002
}
```

im trying with updateMany

````
const doc = await User.updateMany(
            {}, 
            { $set: { 
                //missing here
              }},
            {
                new: true, 
                runValidators : true
            });```
````

Comment: Hello, first I want to ask about the data. Is it from MongoDB or just a JSON file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify object property in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691833/modify-object-property-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: You ask `how to add a number to a integer field using nodejs` but your attempt is not node but mongo

Comment: You might not want to use a number type for phone number fields - I would probably prefer a string type. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's the best solution, but

```
parseInt('91' + user.phonenumber.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

EITHER add
910000000000

`data.forEach(item => item.phonenumber += 910000000000)`

OR

concatenate "91" and convert the string back to number

`data.forEach(item => item.phonenumber = +("91"+item.phonenumber))`

```js
const data =  [{
"_id": "6137392141bbb7723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":9000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":9000000002
}]

data.forEach(item => item.phonenumber += 910000000000)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Suppose that you have a data from as an array

```
[{
"_id": "6137392141bbb7723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000002
}]
```

First of all, you need to parse it to JavaScript, if it's a file you require fs module to be able to extract the data.

```
// parse to js
const array = JSON.parse(data);
const formattedArray = array.map( user => ({...user, phonenumber:  Number(`91${user. phonenumber}`) })) 
const newData = JSON.stringify(formattedArray)
```

That is it, I hope it can help you